# 404. That’s an error. The requested URL was not found on this server in laravel at 000webhost

Tags: php, laravel, public-html

I upload all files and folder on 000webhost and change name public to public_html. so user can now access home page but after clicking on home page and redirecting to some other page but it is showing above error. I'm getting stuck now so can you tell me any solution for 000webhost with laravel. I read some documents too but nothing helpful.

Comment: Can you share the directory structure of your files?

Comment: Using laravel so as same as laravel consist. I just put all files and folder on 000webhost and one thing i made change is replace public name to publich_html as folder name

Comment: `http://kisanotpdemo.000webhostapp.com/` it's not working. @AntonisTsimourtos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution of it myself.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php`
```

save it as `.htcaccess` and put it into `public_html` folder.

Comment: Please use the green checkmark to mark this question as your answer

Comment: I'm not able to do this can you do this? @milo526